# Multidimensional Lists in C#

Tags: c#, list

At the moment I am using one list to store one part of my data, and it's working perfectly in this format:

```
Item
----------------
Joe Bloggs
George Forman
Peter Pan
```

Now, I would like to add another line to this list, for it to work like so:

```
NAME                    EMAIL
------------------------------------------------------
Joe Bloggs              joe@bloggs.com
George Forman           george@formangrills.co
Peter Pan               me@neverland.com
```

I've tried using this code to create a list within a list, and this code is used in another method in a foreach loop:

```
// Where List is instantiated
List<List<string>> list2d = new List<List<string>>

...

// Where DataGrid instance is given the list
dg.DataSource = list2d;
dg.DataBind();

...


// In another method, where all people add their names and emails, then are added
// to the two-dimensional list
foreach (People p in ppl.results) {
    list.Add(results.name);
    list.Add(results.email);
    list2d.Add(list);
}
```

When I run this, I get this result:

```
Capacity Count 
----------------
16       16 
16       16 
16       16
...      ...
```

Where am I going wrong here. How can I get the output I desire with the code I am using right now?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but this doesn't look like a list of lists, but rather a list of records, each with two fields.  If so, perhaps that's how you should be modeling this.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Why don't you use a `List<People>` instead of a `List<List<string>>` ?

Comment: I was about to say that it wouldn't work for me, then I changed my DataGrid variable and now I feel like an idiot. Thank you!

Answer (score 45):

Highly recommend something more like this:

```
public class Person {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
}

var people = new List<Person>();
```

Easier to read, easy to code.

Comment: I like this answer, making a class is more clean and appropriate in my case :)

Answer (score 9):

If for some reason you don't want to define a `Person` class and use `List<Person>` as advised, you can use a tuple, such as (C# 7):

```
var people = new List<(string Name, string Email)>
{
  ("Joe Bloggs", "joe@bloggs.com"),
  ("George Forman", "george@formangrills.co"),
  ("Peter Pan", "me@neverland.com")
};

var georgeEmail = people[1].Email;
```

The `Name` and `Email` member names are optional, you can omit them and access them using `Item1` and `Item2` respectively.

There are defined tuples for up to 8 members.

For earlier versions of C#, you can still use a `List<Tuple<string, string>>` (or preferably `ValueTuple` using [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/)), but you won't benefit from customized member names.

Answer (score 5):

Where does the variable results come from?

This block:

```
foreach (People p in ppl.results) {
    list.Add(results.name);
    list.Add(results.email);
    list2d.Add(list);
}
```

Should probably read more like:

```
foreach (People p in ppl.results) {
    var list = new List<string>();
    list.Add(p.name);
    list.Add(p.email);
    list2d.Add(list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `List<Person>` or a `HashSet<Person>`.

Answer (score 1):

It's old but thought I'd add my two cents...
Not sure if it will work but try using a KeyValuePair:

```
 List<KeyValuePair<?, ?>> LinkList = new List<KeyValuePair<?, ?>>();
 LinkList.Add(new KeyValuePair<?, ?>(Object, Object));
```

You'll end up with something like this:

```
 LinkList[0] = <Object, Object>
 LinkList[1] = <Object, Object>
 LinkList[2] = <Object, Object>
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Please show more of your code.

If that last piece of code declares and initializes the `list` variable outside the loop you're basically reusing the same list object, thus adding everything into one list.

Also show where .Capacity and .Count comes into play, how did you get those values?

Comment: Then you need to show us your code. If you can't make heads or tails of your own code, we can't either unless you post it.