# How to add new items to multiDimensional Array

Tags: c#

How do I add new to items to this Array?

```
public static string[,] myArray = new string[,] { { "1", "1a" }, { "2", "2a" } };

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    myArray.add("3", "3a"); // error

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myArray[i, 0] +", "+ myArray[i, 1]);
    }
}
```

thank you.

Comment: I think you want a List<> or other collection type. Simple Arrays like this have a fixed size determined at initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are fixed once you've created them. Use a `List` when you want to add items. Even though you don't provide dimensions, these are inferred from the declaration and cannot be changed later on.

Answer (score 3):

When you defined your array:

```
public static string[,] myArray = new string[,] { { "1", "1a" }, { "2", "2a" } };
```

You already defined the size of it. You can not change the dimension of an Array once you have already defined it.

If you want to Add new items later, as the others said, you can create an empty array (with the variable name that you want for it) and another list where you can add your new values. You can later use `myArray = List.ToArray()` to manipulate your array.

I would recommend you to check this out: [@SO: Multidimensional List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222117/multidimensional-lists-in-c)

Comment: myArray = List.ToArray()? what do you mean?

Comment: List<string> myList = new List<int>();
        myList.Add("Item1");
        myList.Add("Item2");
        myArray = myList.ToArray();

Comment: Do you need necessarily the array to be multidimensional[,] ?

Comment: yes I do need multidimensional array or multidimensional list very badly.

Comment: I should have been more explicit. Can your multidimensional Array be of and string[][] (simplifies the problem) or must it be [,] ? Or can you have two arrays and then run them with i & j ?